# Huge meshes (how to export, textures etc.)

Tags: mesh, texturing

So i've got a huge mesh of an house at the moment, with around 900k faces. I could just export the mesh from blender to unreal engine 4, but its way too large, and most of the time it just crashes. What would be the best way to export this mesh? And if it has to be in parts, whats the best way to do that?

Also, is it a better idea to apply textures in blender or in unreal engine 4?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7XBB.png

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that all one mesh?  If so that's a bad idea in general. The windows all look similar...can you only export one and instance it around the scene inside Unreal?  How close will you get to that spire on top of the pointy roof?   If you won't get close, it doesn't need to be perfectly round.  Can you get away with an alpha texture for that grid/mesh at the bottom of the house, instead of using all those polys?

Answer (score 1):

You should decrease polycount. To achive this use decimate modifier or remesh modifier

Comment: That's the problem. The house also has an interior. Should i use the modifier on every mesh then? And how should i export all the meshes, in one group or one at a time?

Comment: Hmm you can set the decimate to about .9 and select all the meshes (the active mesh must be with modifier) and then click crtl+l and copy modifires

Comment: It'll copy this decimate to all of your meshes

Comment: Ah that works, thanks! The face count droped from 900k to 300k. I grouped up all the meshes and can now export it. Thanks alot man! One thing, is it better to apply textures in unreal engine 4 or in blender when exporting?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know. I always export it as 1 object because zbrush can separate objects with diffrent materials, maybe in ue4 it works as well

Comment: Double answer. Consider deleting this one, or merge the two.